# Copying Map with modification on values

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, java-stream

I have a simple DTO class:

```java
@Builder
public class AccountDto {
  private Long id;
  private BigDecimal balance;
  private Currency currency;
}
```

`Currency` is an `enum` of my own which maintains about 300 different currency symbols.

For testing purposes, I want to create 10 `AccountDTO`s that correspond to one currency, then 10 that correspond to another, and so on and so forth. The following code generates some sequential IDs:

```java
public static final Map<Currency, List<Long>> ACCOUNT_IDS_OF_GIVEN_CURRENCIES = Map.of(
          Currency.USD, LongStream.rangeClosed(1L, 10L).boxed().toList(),
          Currency.GBP, LongStream.rangeClosed(11L, 20L).boxed().toList(),
          Currency.EUR, LongStream.rangeClosed(21L, 30L).boxed().toList(),
          Currency.INR, LongStream.rangeClosed(31L, 40L).boxed().toList()
  );
```

Now, I would like to create `AccountDTO` instances based on these IDs that I generated into another map keyed by the exact same `Currency` instances. While I *could* do it like this:

```java
public static final Map<Currency, List<AccountDto>> ACCOUNT_DTOS_OF_GIVEN_CURRENCIES = generateAccountDTOsBasedOnIds(ACCOUNT_IDS_OF_GIVEN_CURRENCIES);

public static Map<Currency, List<AccountDto>> generateAccountDTOsBasedOnIds(Map<Currency, List<Long>> inputMap){
    Map<Currency, List<AccountDto>> accountDtosOfGivenCurrencies = new HashMap<>();
    for(Map.Entry<Currency, List<Long>> entry : inputMap.entrySet()){
      accountDtosOfGivenCurrencies.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().stream()
              .map(id->AccountDto.builder()
                      .id(id)
                      .balance(BigDecimal.TEN)
                      .currency(entry.getKey())
                      .build())
              .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
    return accountDtosOfGivenCurrencies;
  }
```

This is rather imperative and inelegant, explicitly allocating a `HashMap`, whereas no such thing was necessary for the `ACCOUNT_IDS_OF_GIVEN_CURRENCIES` `Map`. I am trying to do this in one fell swoop, using streams, `Map.ofEntries()`, `entrySet()`, `Map.Entry.copyOf()` ([Java 17 feature](https://marco.dev/java-17-copyof)) and other ways, but so far I have failed. The closest I've come to is the following, which fails at compile-time because `Map.entry()` is not an instantiable type.

```java
public static final Map<Currency, List<AccountDto>> ACCOUNT_DTOS_OF_GIVEN_CURRENCIES = Map.ofEntries(
          ACCOUNT_IDS_OF_GIVEN_CURRENCIES.entrySet().stream().map(currencyListEntry -> Map.entry(currencyListEntry.getKey(),
                  currencyListEntry.getValue().stream().map(id->
                          AccountDto.builder()
                                  .id(id)
                                  .balance(BigDecimal.TEN)
                                  .currency(currencyListEntry.getKey())
                                  .build())
                          .toList())).toArray(Map.Entry::new));
```

[image: Compile-time error in my solution.]

Any ideas about how this could be solved elegantly and without an intermediate instantiation of a `Map` type like `HashMap` or `TreeMap`? Completely open to solutions that might use ApacheCommons, Guava, any reasonable library I could add to my `pom`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`toMap` collector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)).

```java
public static final Map<Currency, List<AccountDto>> ACCOUNT_DTOS_OF_GIVEN_CURRENCIES = 
    ACCOUNT_IDS_OF_GIVEN_CURRENCIES
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
            e -> e.getValue().stream()
                .map(id -> AccountDto.builder().id(id)
                        .balance(BigDecimal.TEN).currency(e.getKey()).build())
                        .toList()));
```

Answer (score 1):

you already had it, but you cant instantiate Map.Entry::new like that becuase it's an interface. replacing it with Collectors.toMap would work

```
public static final Map<Currency, List<AccountDto>> ACCOUNT_DTOS_OF_GIVEN_CURRENCIES =
        ACCOUNT_IDS_OF_GIVEN_CURRENCIES
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(currencyListEntry ->
                        Map.entry(
                                currencyListEntry.getKey(),
                                currencyListEntry.getValue()
                                        .stream()
                                        .map(id->
                                                AccountDto.builder()
                                                .id(id)
                                                .balance(BigDecimal.TEN)
                                                .currency(currencyListEntry.getKey())
                                                .build()).toList()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: as I am new to declarative vs imperative fight, why is imperative approach not elegant ? I seem to understand it better, and also it seems like easier to code :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm accepting the other one only because it's a bit shorter by bringing the appropriate `Collector` to the mix sooner. Many people would argue that the imperative approach is more readable and easier to code, as you said, but as I've progressed in my career in software I've learned that [new is glue](https://ardalis.com/new-is-glue/), and if you can avoid binding your solution to a particular implementation and let the language do it for you as it wishes (perhaps switching the binding dynamically after a few operations), then you should strive towards that.

Comment: sure, @Unmitigated answer is the better approach, I just didn't wanna change much to your code to point out the differences you should make. also thanks for your tip :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to create 10 accounts for each currency of your enum, you don't realy need the intermediate step of creating a currency-to-id-map. If for example you have an enum like:

```
enum Currency {
    USD,
    GBP,
    EUR,
    INR
}
```

and your DTO given as above:

```
@Builder
public class AccountDto {
  private Long id;
  private BigDecimal balance;
  private Currency currency;
}
```

then you could do something like below:

```
//a function that returns an AccountDto given a long value, using this value as an Id and chosing the i / 10 index of the Currency.values() array
LongFunction<AccountDto> func = l -> AccountDto.builder()
                                               .id(l)
                                               .balance(BigDecimal.TEN)
                                               .currency(Currency.values()[(int)(l - 1) / 10])
                                               .build();

Map<Currency, List<AccountDto>> map = LongStream.rangeClosed(1, Currency.values().length * 10)
                                                .mapToObj(func::apply)
                                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AccountDto::getCurrency));

map.forEach((k,v) -> {
    System.out.println(k);
    v.forEach(acc -> System.out.println(acc.toString().indent(4)));
});
```